# How to call and start the map in full screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to start the map in fullscreen: map.fullscreen
I tried:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map.fullscreen")
```

then

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("#map.fullscreen")
```

but it didn't start with them ap in full screen.
the goal is to start either with the map in full screen or like now in the custom size 150px,90px

edited my question with the html code too.
including the style css and javascript.

The full code of the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Google Maps Api</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="loadbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
  
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
  
<style>#map
    {
        width: 150px;
        height:90px;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-right: -50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
    }
    
    #map.fullscreen {
        position: fixed;
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;
      }</style>
  
<script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap&v=weekly&language=he"
      defer
    ></script>

<script>let map;

    function initMap() {
        // The location of Uluru
        const uluru = { lat: 32.1582615544072, lng: 34.89155037133181 };
        // The map, centered at Uluru
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          zoom: 11,
          center: uluru,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          fullscreenControl: true,
          
          options: {
    gestureHandling: 'greedy'
  }
        });

        
        // Create the DIV to hold the control.
      const centerControlDiv = document.createElement("div");
      // Create the control.
      const centerControl = createCenterControl(map);
      // Append the control to the DIV.
      centerControlDiv.appendChild(centerControl);
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(centerControlDiv);
    
        const chicago = { lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65 };
    
        /**
         * Creates a control that recenters the map on Chicago.
         */
        function createCenterControl(map) {
          const controlButton = document.createElement("button");
        
          // Set CSS for the control.
          controlButton.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
          controlButton.style.border = "2px solid #fff";
          controlButton.style.borderRadius = "3px";
          controlButton.style.boxShadow = "0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)";
          controlButton.style.color = "rgb(25,25,25)";
          controlButton.style.cursor = "pointer";
          controlButton.style.fontFamily = "Roboto,Arial,sans-serif";
          controlButton.style.fontSize = "16px";
          controlButton.style.lineHeight = "28px";
          controlButton.style.borderLeftWidth = "8px";
          controlButton.style.margin = "8px 8px 22px 0";
          controlButton.style.padding = "0 5px";
          controlButton.style.textAlign = "center";
          controlButton.textContent = "Center Map";
          controlButton.title = "Click to recenter the map";
          controlButton.type = "button";
          
          // Setup the click event listeners: simply set the map to Chicago.
          controlButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            map.setCenter(chicago);
          });
          return controlButton;
        }
    
        const rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: "#FF0000",
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map,
            bounds: {
                north: uluru.lat - 0.005,
                south: uluru.lat + 0.005,
                west: uluru.lng - 0.005,
                east: uluru.lng + 0.005,
            },
          });
      
}
    
      window.initMap = initMap;</script>
</body>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="loadbar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class='progress' id="progress_div">
  
  
  <h1 id="loading-message">...טוען מפה</h1>
   <div class='bar' id='bar1'></div>
   <div class='percent' id='percent1'></div>
</div>

<div i  
   <div id="content">
    
    
   </div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" id="progress_width" value="0">
<div>

</html>
```

Comment: You've included your CSS and your Javascript, but not your HTML. Edit your question to add a snippet containing all three which demonstrates the problem, then I'll help you.

Comment: @BrettDonald edited my question. if you can please also help me with the loadbar to display the bar and the text of the bar in the middle of the screen now it's showing it on the top. thank you very much.

Comment: No, we don't want **all** your code. You need to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which demonstrates the problem **as a snippet**.